# Can't get GCM push messages being sent properly

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

So my GCM push message works if I use this test link

http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/gcm.html

Here's the response

```
{ "multicast_id":7724943165862866717,
  "success":1,
  "failure":0,
  "canonical_ids":0,
  "results":[{"message_id":"0:1418649384921891% 7fd2b314f9fd7ecd"}]}
```

However if I push using my own service using node push service using the toothlessgear/node-gcm lib
https://github.com/ToothlessGear/node-gcm I get a success message on the server but no msg makes it to the client

```
{ multicast_id: 5130374164465991000,
  success: 1,
  failure: 0,
  canonical_ids: 0,
  results: [ { message_id: '0:1418649238305331%7fd2b3145bca2e79' } ] }
```

I also tried the same message using pushwoosh and push woosh doesn't work either.  How come I'm getting a success message on the server, but no push is received on the client on the latter two services.  Is there some sort of ip configuration that I need to do, or some sort of certificate?  I've used the same google api server key which is open to all ips on all 3 of these services.

Why does the response show success on the latter but no msg gets received on the client?

Node service server side code

```
var gcm = require('node-gcm');

// create a message with default values
var message = new gcm.Message();

// or with object values
var message = new gcm.Message({
    collapseKey: 'demo',
    delayWhileIdle: true,
    timeToLive: 3,
    data: {
        key1: 'message1',
        key2: 'message2'
    }
});

var sender = new gcm.Sender('insert Google Server API Key here');
var registrationIds = ['regId1'];

/**
 * Params: message-literal, registrationIds-array, No. of retries, callback-function
 **/
sender.send(message, registrationIds, 4, function (err, result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: Since I've tried sending from the pushwoosh service, and I'm getting the same issue.  It seems like that first androidbegin test link is the only one that gets a push message delivered to the galaxy s2 I'm testing with.  Is there some sort of version compatibility where the older Galaxy s2s can't recieve messages from a newer GCM service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the pushes were correctly being sent, my issue was with the cordova plugin on the client which requires that the android payload for "message" or "title" be set.  The sample php just coincidentally was setting the message property and that's why it worked.

Updating the code to add the following to the data

data: {message:'test'}

works correctly

Comment: Hey could you have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33791798/why-am-i-unable-to-receive-push-notification-on-android-by-ionic-framework)