# Why am I unable to receive push Notification on Android by ionic framework

Tags: android, push-notification, ionic-framework, google-cloud-messaging

I had written this small test app to test the New ionic push and in the backend I am using Android Google Cloud Messaging Service. I am getting success from the android GCM in my frontEnd

```
data: Object
canonical_ids: 0
failure: 0
multicast_id: 8830892721591033000
results: Array[1]
success: 1
__proto__: Object
```

This is the front End Code

```
app.run(function($ionicPlatform, $ionicPush,$http) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
   $ionicPush.init({
  "onNotification": function(notification) {
    var payload = notification.payload;
    console.log(payload);
    console.log(notification);
  },
  "onRegister": function(data) {
    console.log(data.token);
  }
});

$ionicPush.register(function(data){
  var reg = {
    regId : data.token
   };
  $http.post('http://app.example.com/sendPushNot', reg)
  .then(function(response){
    console.log(response);
  }, function (error){
    console.log(error);
  });
});
```

and in my backend

```
var message = new gcm.Message({
    collapseKey: 'demo',
    priority: 'high',
    contentAvailable: true,
    delayWhileIdle: true,
    timeToLive: 3,
    //restrictedPackageName: "somePackageName",
    dryRun: false,
    data: {
        key1: 'message1',
        key2: 'message2'
    },
    notification: {
        title: "Hello, World",
        icon: "ic_launcher",
        body: "This is a notification that will be displayed ASAP."
    }
});

    console.log(message);
    var sender = new gcm.Sender('AIzaSyB9Lz**********9mHJuH5if1m5k5JOVMw'); 

    var regTokens =  [];
    regTokens.push(req.body.regId);

        sender.send(message, { registrationTokens: regTokens }, function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
            }
            else {

                 console.log(result);
                 res.status(200);
                 res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
                 res.send(result);
            }
        });
```

but still I am unable to receive any push Notification. I am not understanding the reason why?

Any anybody else spot anything. I am using [node-gcm](https://github.com/ToothlessGear/node-gcm) in the backend

**EDIT EDIT EDIT**
The problem could be anywhere server or frontEnd.
I have exactly narrowed down the scope of the problem using [this](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/gcm.html). Now using this as there is no payload I am able to see the console logs in `onNotification` listener. It means My listener is correct... partially as I am able to send the data from server to Frontend by using only data field. 
Now the problem could be that Ionic.Push is not capable of receiving the notifications or could be that node-gcm is not able to send the plugins correctly
Behold your breath for the ultimate showdown between me and these badass plugins.

Comment: Did you install the push notifications plugin?

Comment: Yes via `ionic plugin add phonegap-plugin-push` also did `ionic config set dev_push false` `ionic push --google-api-key AIzaSyB****************JOVMw`

`ionic config set gcm_key 14*****55078`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, guys here it goes, after my final showdown I was the winner. I figured out finally. I had not entered the `app_id` field. It was something related completely to ionic so it wouldn't be true for android people. It was a small issue. Had I looked at the source code earlier. I would have known it by now.  But anyways four days to solve and finally it's working. 
If anythings is not working post in the comments I'll help you out.

So the flow goes like this.

```
ionic config set dev_push false

ionic push --google-api-key AIzaSyB9L****************5if1m5k5JOVMw

ionic config set gcm_key 148*****5078

ionic config set app_id (some_alphanumeric_value found on ionic.io and is availble after you have done ionic io init)
```

Answer (score 0):

can you confirm that the http request to send token to server is executed? if i'm not mistaken, android tokens are received in a push notification to the phone via gcm in your onRegister callback as:

```
app.run(function($ionicPlatform, $ionicPush,$http) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
   $ionicPush.init({
  "onNotification": function(notification) {
    var payload = notification.payload;
    console.log(payload);
    console.log(notification);
  },
  "onRegister": function(data) {
    console.log(data.token);
    //works for android
    var reg  = { regId: data.token };        
      $http.post('http://app.example.com/sendPushNot', reg)
      .then(function(response){
        console.log(response);
      }, function (error){
        console.log(error);
      });
      }
    });

    $ionicPush.register(function(data){
       //works for ios 
      var reg = {
        regId : data.token
       };
      $http.post('http://app.example.com/sendPushNot', reg)
      .then(function(response){
        console.log(response);
      }, function (error){
        console.log(error);
      });
    });
```

Comment: It is exexcuted and hence I have also pasted the response. I will check on that onRegister thing right away. See you in few mins

Comment: As expected it didn't work. It worked once. Damn I should have saved that file.s

Comment: updated my answer. could you log req.body in your server side code and confirm that youre receiving a token now? although gcm sends the token in to your device and it shows in console.log, I don't think you were receiving it in your server side code...

Comment: I received it on the other side and the sender.send function was executed and the result was success. (That is the first output I posted and I verified it with the server).